How to debug production containers using kubectl debug under root user?
I’m facing an issue related to our strict security policies, which are configured according to best practices. Below is the security context we are using:
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: <user id, any except 0>
    privileged: false
  containers:
    securityContext:
      runAsNonRoot: true
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false

This setup works well to harden our production containers, but we’re running into a problem when it comes to debugging.
For example, when we need to verify network connectivity using TCPDUMP, we can use kubectl debug --profile=netadmin. Full command:
 kubectl debug -it <target-container>  --image=nicolaka/netshoot --profile=netadmin --target=<target-container> -- tcpdump

This allows us to get the necessary NET_ADMIN, but the debugging container runs under a non-root user, resulting in the following error:
Warning: would violate PodSecurity "baseline:latest": non-default capabilities (containers "debugger-jb8sv", "debugger-zklnx", "debugger-mmt72", "debugger-gd8lt" must not include "NET_ADMIN", "NET_RAW" in securityContext.capabilities.add)
tcpdump: eth0: You don't have permission to perform this capture on that device
(socket: Operation not permitted)

I guess it should be fixed with sysadmin profile but as of now, the sysadmin profile is not available in kubectl 1.29.
Can anyone suggest a way to tackle this issue while maintaining our security standards? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
